# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, forms, spring-boot, jpa, put

I am studying spring boot and spring jpa .
I was able to successfully read and write into the database, but the problem occurs while updating the data.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I am trying to update data of table : Person ( Id, Name , Age) using a html form. It accepts the data, and using spring jpa  I am trying to update it in MySQL database.

I am getting the following at console when trying to update the data, after submitting the form

```
> WARN 5176 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
> Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

My code is here : 
updateperson form :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Enter new details</h1>
    <form action="updatePerson" method="post">
        Id   : <input type="number" name="id"><br>
        Name :<input type = "text" name = "name"><br>
        Age : <input type = "number" name = "age"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PersonRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person , Integer> {
    List<Person> findByName(String name);
    List<Person> findByAge(int age);
    List<Person> findAll();
}
```

PersonController.java

```
    package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;


    @GetMapping("update")
    public String updatePerson(){
        System.out.println("update to updateperson html");
        return "updateperson";
    }
    @PutMapping("/updatePerson")
    public String updatePerson(Person person){
        System.out.println("UPDATING TO" + person.getAge()+" : "+person.getName() + " : "+person.getPid());
        personRepository.save(person);
        return "updateperson";
    }  

}
```

Person.java

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int pid;

    String name;
    int age;

     public Person() {
    }

    public Person(int pid, String name, int age) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

//getter and setters
}
```

The URL to which I'm sending the request:

```
localhost:8080/updatePerson?id=4&name=personame&age=34
```

Comment: please share the request URL, too.

Comment: localhost:8080/updatePerson?id=4&name=personame&age=34

Answer (score 0):

If you check the URL: localhost:8080/updatePerson?id=4&name=personame&age=34, the method you are trying to access (updatePerson) is a `PUT`, so you should send a `PUT` instead of a `GET`.
You can see the method type in the annotation:

```
@PutMapping("/updatePerson")
```

Depending on how you are doing the request there should be someplace to set the method you are using. Also, looking at the URL, it does not seem to fit any request since in the /updatePerson you are expecting an object Person in the body but are sending: `?id=4&name=personame&age=34` as query parameters.

An example of a curl with a body that would be accepted by your method:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"personame","age":"34"}' http://localhost:8080/updatePerson
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/updatePerson?id=4&name=personame&age=34

Answer (score 0):

have a better look on your endpoints:

```
@GetMapping("update")
public String updatePerson(){
    System.out.println("update to updateperson html");
    return "updateperson";
}
@PutMapping("/updatePerson")
public String updatePerson(Person person){
    System.out.println("UPDATING TO" + person.getAge()+" : "+person.getName() + " : "+person.getPid());
    personRepository.save(person);
    return "updateperson";
}
```

your `GET` and `PUT` methods have different paths and you try to access `GET` method with `Put` path as you said in the comment.

What you can do to fix it:

- change `GET` path to `@GetMapping("updatePerson")`
- call your `GET` path by this URL: `localhost:8080/update` not `localhost:8080/updatePerson`

Comment: In this case the updatePerson should still be a PUT or POST since it receives a `Person` object and saves it to the DB.

Comment: in the 'html form' i have declared method as POST ( HTML doesnt support PUT), though when instead i use @ GetMapping instead of @ PutMapping, the data is inserted, (not updated) as separate tuple( since it is get) ,  so how will update data in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `GET` request while you have added a `@PutMapping` in your `updatePerson` method. If you want to access `updatePerson` then you should try to hit that endpoint with a `PUT` method.

Use `GET` method when accessing `localhost:8080/update` and use `PUT` method when accessing `localhost:8080/updatePerson`

Comment: i have @ GetMapping for /update, and @ PutMapping for /updatePerson , the problem is data to /updatePerson comes from an HTML Form, which only supports GET and POST method, even though i have used 'POST' in my html form ( in updateperson.html document), my data sent by form is in the url (which is supposed to happen for only GET method).